# Is it possible to save multiple radiogroup using one shared preference method

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I have following method:

```
private void savePref(RadioGroup rg_group1) {
        int rg_group1_CheckId = rg_group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        //int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_RG_NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("NumberOfQuestions", rg_group1_CheckId);      
        editor.commit();
    }
```

I want to save another radio group called rg_group2. Will i have to create separate method for this? Or is there a way to add another radiogroup to save preferences for both radiogroups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to save the other radiogroup info in another key value pair of the sharedpreferences. But you can use a single method to do so. SOmething like

```
private void savePref(RadioGroup rg_group1 , String key) {
        int rg_group1_CheckId = rg_group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        //int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_RG_NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, rg_group1_CheckId);      
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: So you mean to add a check for key? Like if (key = 0) save value for group1 if key = 1 save value for group2?

Comment: there are several ways to do it .. you can put the preference name like .. savePref(radiogrp1, "NumberOfQuestions");, savePref(radiogrp1, "NumberOfAnswers"); liek that/.. or you can do it in many other ways

Comment: But even if i do the way you are suggesting. I still have to write if statement and then have to write pref.edit() two times or have to write if statement two times. Isnt it same amount of code as having two separate methods? So which one is better?

Comment: @NoviceMe: you don't need to add if statement anywhere.because you are now passing the `key` as argument which will be used by `sharedpreference` to store your `rg_group1` data which is also being passed as argument.